# How to get Post parameters on IsAuthorized of AuthorizeAttribute ASP.NET Web.API MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I need to get values of my Post Parameters at the time of Authorization. Searchers on web but no solution is working. `ActionArguments` count always showing 0 and not able to find values in `ActionDescriptor.GetParameters()`

Here is my code:

**POST model -**

```
public class XyzModel
{
   public int Prop1 { get; set; }
   public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

**Custom Authorize Attribute -**

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute  : AuthorizeAttribute
{
   protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
   {    
     bool conditions = // here I need to check value of my model (XyzModel) properties 
    if(conditions)
    {
       return true;
    }

      return false;
    }        
}
```

**Code in controller -**

```
[HttpPost]
[CustomAuthorizeAttribute]       
public IHttpActionResult MyAction(XyzModel model)
{
    // my work here
}
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access model property of ActionArguments it will return XyzModel object. than you can perform any operation on its properties:

```
XyzModel model = (XyzModel)actionContext.ActionArguments["model"];
```

In your code it will be like this:

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute  : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var prop1 = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["Prop1"];
        var prop2 = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["Prop2"];
        bool conditions = // add conditions based on above properties
        if(conditions)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }        
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply . but as I mentioned in my question ActionArguments count are showing 0.

Comment: ohh okay i did not noticed that.  Thanks.

Comment: If ActionArguments count is 0 than posted data's properties can be access as this: HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["Prop1"]; HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["Prop2"]; I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I believe, you will not get post parameter value in `AuthorizeAttribute` as `AuthorizeAttribute` methods are called before action's parameter binding.

For your scenario, you can use `ActionFilterAttribute` which executes only after action's parameter binding. You can create your custom filter attribute by using `ActionFilterAttribute`

```
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;

public class CheckMyPostDataFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        XyzModel model = (XyzModel )actionContext.ActionArguments["model"]; // you will get data here 

        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
    }
}
```

You can simply decorate above `CheckMyPostDataFilter` filter in your action :

```
[HttpPost]
[CheckMyPostData]       
public IHttpActionResult MyAction(XyzModel model)
{
    // my work here
}
```

Comment: As far as i know `OnActionExecuting` does not take `HttpActionContext` as parameter. Actually it takes `ActionExecutingContext` as parameter.

Comment: HttpActionContext  also worked using System.Web.Http.Filters .. ActionExecutingContext  uses System.Web.Mvc.Filters ..

Comment: Sorry! my mistake. `System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute` for web-api method `OnActionExecuting` takes `HttpActionContext` parameter.

Comment: while `System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute` method `OnActionExecuting` takes `ActionExecutingContext` parameter.

Comment: and changing to ActionExecutingContext using System.Web.Mvc.Filters not working for me . .only HttpActionContext is working

Comment: @Akash .. sorry had to change marked answer . but thanks a lot for your time . hope this will help others

Answer (score 1):

You can use Request Body Input Stream to read the entire Body content as below

```
public sealed class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var req = HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream;
        string body = new StreamReader(req).ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Comment: This works for me, the rest of them state to use `HttpContext.Current.Request.Params`, however, there I could not find any of my parameters.

Comment: You can only read from InputStream once. If you do it in the attribute then the model binder will not be able to read the body to map to action method.